# Adapter to connect 3/8 quick release to standard garden hose

Tags: hose, gardening, pressure-washer, outdoorfaucet

I have a MJJC gun for car washing. It has a nilfisk connector also it has optional 3/8 quick connector (as in the photos) . It supposed to be connected to a pressure machine. But I'm curious if it's possible to connect either that connector (nilfisk or 3/8 quick) directly to any standard garden hose connected to outdoor faucet ? What additional adapter should I get? Is it possible? If yes, can anyone share me the link to the connector/adapter? [image]
[image]

Comment: Find what connections you can get on the mating coupler, and then it's a matter of GHT (garden hose thread) to that in as many or as few steps as it takes. Product recommendations / link to product / do your shopping for you are explicitly off topic. I'll doubt there a one step adapter, but I could be wrong. I'm sure that with 2-3 adapters you can get there, multiple ways.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that something intended to be used as a pressure washer attachment would work very well at normal garden-hose pressure.